# which mathematical logic books do you recommend for undergraduate students?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I am studying mathematics at the undergraduate level and I am interested in the world of mathematical logic.
I would like to know the opinion about which books or texts are recommended for an introduction to the subject and then a deepening?

I am grateful to all those people who give me their opinion or recommendation of texts or notes, on mathematical logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Beginning Mathematical Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl) Study Guide which is a cheap pbk and is also freely downloadable as a PDF. It has extensive suggestions at various levels across the different fields of mathematical logic.

The Guide is downloaded about 2K times a month, so I guess people are finding it useful.